# Is there any plan to take out "features" from next versions of javascript?

Tags: programming-languages, javascript

I'm looking to learn javascript (now for real) and I've had a look on the [latest version](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html) of ES6 which is supposed to be frozen in terms of features set. 
It seems to be the pretty much same as ES5 plus new stuff(features). My main complain is that there so many ways to accomplish the same thing so I'm wondering if there is any plan to take out some of the old "features" or if it keeps building up on top of the old specs(i.e. until it becomes a big mess).

Comment: It's hard to throw away features when you have to preserve backward compatibility. Also the annexes in the standards documents have notes about specific compatibility changes between versions, etc. Did you read those?

Comment: Well, some "features" will unfortunately stay there forever: http://wtfjs.com.

Comment: You could ask the same question of any hyper-popular programming language or software product. C++ also has a bunch of features they'd love to get rid of, and are effectively dead in modern versions but still have to be supported until the end of time.

Comment: @Den, fortunately i've just found out that there is still hope. See https://developers.google.com/v8/experiments

Answer (score 2):

I disagree, the main goal of ES6 is not to introduced new ways "to accomplish the same thing" but actually cover some areas that were not covered at all.

Generators are extremely helpful for the class of tasks where you should iterate through a big list of items but you don't need to keep all this items in memory at one time. This is something that just was very hard to emulate.

Or let's take a look on Sets and Maps - before now you were limited by the fact that there was impossible to have any keys in hash other than strings.

Varargs, optional arguments, arrow functions, string interpolation, destructuring assignment - all these, yes, actually can be treated as a sugar syntax but from my experience I hardly can treat current approaches competitive with new ones, new one are better and most likely will always be used instead.

So, saying all this I can actually think of features that can be excluded "in exchange". Even if the maximum compatibility won't be treated as crucial aspect (it does), there's nothing much to throw away.

As of small incositencies, they are actually get fixed by introducing new stricter mini APIs - check out, for example, [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN). From time to time older APIs are deprecated and even excluded but this not a fast process and actually it should not be.

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript ist the single most compatibility-constrained language that ever existed.

In general, developers can't choose the version of the implementation (or even which implementation) that is going to be used to run their code, because it is installed on the users' machine. Users can't choose the version of the app they run, because the code gets delivered by the remote website. Users often can't even choose which version of which implementation they are running, because the implementation is bound to the browser and the browser is dictated by the OS, some IT department policy, or backwards-compatibility constraints of *other* unrelated websites.

Websites are (should be) eternal. There may be some ECMAScript-heavy website that hasn't been maintained for 10 years, but you still need to be able to visit it 10 years from now, with a browser with an embedded ECMAScript 10 engine.

Giving those *extreme* backwards-compatibility constraints, it is pretty much *impossible* to remove a feature once it is there. `var` is one such feature that should probably be removed, but likely never will.

However, there is a transition feature: ECMAScript 5 and 6 have a so-called *Strict Mode* which is triggered by a `"use strict"` declaration. Strict mode is not just a subset of normal mode, it may actually have different semantics. And future versions of ECMAScript are usually built on top of the previous version's strict mode. E.g. ECMAScript 6 is built on ECMAScript 5 strict mode. New language features automatically trigger strict mode, e.g. module and class declarations in ECMAScript 6 will always be evaluated in strict mode, regardless of whether there is a `"use strict"` declaration.

Comment: With the User-Agent string clients can effectively choose which kind of ECMAScript they would like to run. Whether the server provides what that UA needs or not is another question. In practice good sites provide a rich client with a fall-back to HTML-only mode if there are known problems with that UA

Comment: It seems there is already a proposal named soundscript[0]. It's a shame that SO moderators close valid/sound questions as "primarily opinion-based". It starts to become a bug reporting tool rather than Q&A.  [0] https://developers.google.com/v8/experiments

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat: I don't understand what you are talking about. No moderators were involved in closing this question. Plus, SO moderators don't even have any powers at all on this site anyway.